# cambio de contenido con select y option

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

tengo un listado de opciones dentro de un select, lo que quiero es que al seleccionar una de ellas el contenido que se encuentra dentro de los comentarios tabe1 y table2 , cambien al momento de seleccionar una de las opciones y a su vez se oculte el otro contenido.

Intento realizarlo con el javascript que se encuentra en la parte baja del código, pero logro hacer que se ejecute la acción de que al momento de seleccionar cambie el contenido de table1 y a su vez el table 2 se oculte.

este es el codigo :

```
<div class="sc-gsTEea dRfmBj" style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
    <label class="sc-dlfnuX ewrGwA" id="boost_list">
        <select id="boost_list" name="boost_list" class="sc-bdfBQB gyYeHq">
              <option>Boost/Hydra/6-Bolt/SRAM XD/Torque Caps</option>
              <option>Boost/Hydra/6-Bolt/Microspline/standard 15mm Caps</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>

<!-- Contenido a cambiar 1 -->
<!-- table 1 -->
<div id="table_boost" class="pad-fade" state="entered" style="transition: all 0.5s ease 0s; opacity: 1; display: block;">
    <dl id="#kit-data" class="product_specs">
        <dt class="product_spec--title">Wheel Spec</dt>
        <dd class="product_spec--detail">Description</dd>
        <dt class="product_spec--title">Wheel Diameter</dt>
        <dd class="product_spec--detail">29”</dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
<!-- table 1 // -->


<!-- Contenido a cambiar 2 -->
<!-- table 2 // -->
 <div id="table_boost" class="pad-fade" state="entered" style="transition: all 0.5s ease 0s; opacity: 1; display: block;">
    <dl id="#kit-data" class="product_specs">
      <dt class="product_spec--title">Wheel Spec</dt>
      <dd class="product_spec--detail">Description</dd>
      <dt class="product_spec--title">Wheel Diameter</dt>
      <dd class="product_spec--detail">29”</dd>
    
  </dl>
</div>
<!-- tabla 2 /  -->


<script>
var l, boost;
    boost = document.querySelectorAll(".table_boost");
        for (l = 0; l < boost.length; l++) {
                boost[l].style.display = "none";
            }
    const selectElement = document.querySelector('#boost_list');
    selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => { 
    document.querySelectorAll('.boost_list').style.display = "block"; 
    });
console.log(boost)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si te he entendido bien, lo que quieres hacer es mostrar uno de los DIV de abajo según la selección hecha (el otro debe ocultarse):

1. No debes tener dos ID iguales en HTML. Ambos DIVs tienen el mismo ID="table_boost". Si tratas de obtener una referencia de alguno (querySelector), te devolverá el primero que encuentre, de manera que no tienes forma de distinguirlos. Cada uno debe tener un ID único.
2. El la acción que desencadena el evento "change" no está haciendo nada en realidad. querySelectorAll te está devolviendo un objeto indefinido (undefined) pues no existe ningún elemento (o en este caso un conjunto de elementos) con la clase ".boost_list".
3. El campo select "boost_list" no está tomando ningún valor pues a las opciones (options) de la lista les falta el atributo "value" que es el que asigna el valor al campo al elegirse la opción.

Solución:

- Asigna los atributos "value" a cada opción del SELECT
- Identifica cada DIV con un ID único
- En la función desencadenada por el evento "change", evalúa la selección (compara el campo "boost_list" con el valor) y según eso muestras el DIV correspondiente) Una forma sencilla de hacerlo es asignar el ID con el mismo nombre del valor de cada opción.
- Para ocultar todos los DIVs de una sola vez, asigna una clase común para esos DIVs y cambias el estilo a display=none

Código:

Valor para el campo select "boost_list"

```html
        <select id="boost_list" name="boost_list" class="sc-bdfBQB gyYeHq">
              <option vaue="boost1">Boost/Hydra/6-Bolt/SRAM XD/Torque Caps</option>
              <option value="boost2">Boost/Hydra/6-Bolt/Microspline/standard 15mm Caps</option>
        </select>

...

<!-- table 1 // -->
<div id="boost1" class="pad-fade" state="entered" style="transition: all 0.5s ease 0s; opacity: 1; display: block;">
...
</div>


...

<!-- table 2 // -->
 <div id="boost2" class="pad-fade" state="entered" style="transition: all 0.5s ease 0s; opacity: 1; display: block;">
...
</div>
```

Script

```javascript
    selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => { 
    
    // oculta todas las tablas
    document.querySelectorAll('.pad-fade').style.display = "none"; 

    // ID según selección hecha
    const tableId = document.querySelector('#boost_list').value();

    // mostrar tabla (DIV)
    document.querySelectorAll(`#${tableId}`).style.display = "block"; 
    });
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias, esta super completa la explicación..el unico problema seria, ¿como puedo hacer para que muestre el primero siempre de la seleccion al abrir la pagina y tambien me dice que selectElement no esta definido.

Comment: Para mostrar solo uno de los DIV, coloca uno con display="block" y el otro con display="none". Para predeterminar el select (asignarle un valor inicial) tienes dos opciones: (a) coloca el atributo value al SELECT con el valor de la primera opción (esta es la mejor opción) o (b) coloca el atributo selected a uno de los OPTION.

Lo otro que preguntas, honestamente no hallo razón.